# Prove $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{bc+3a}}\ge \sqrt{\frac{81\sqrt{3}-27}{26}}$ for $a, b, c\ge 0; ab + bc + ca =1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> **Problem**. Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=1,$ prove that: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{bc+3a}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ca+3b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab+3c}}\ge \sqrt{\frac{81\sqrt{3}-27}{26}}.$$

I posted it [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h3076209_inequality_marathon). See post #87. I gave an idea after that which is very ugly.

Anyway, I will rewrite it in detail now.

By AM-GM:$$3a+bc\le 3\sqrt{3}a\frac{\left(\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{b+c}{4}\right)^2+\dfrac{1}{3}}{2\left(\dfrac{a}{2}+\dfrac{b+c}{4}\right)}+bc=\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{8}.\frac{3\left(2a+b+c\right)^2+16}{2a+b+c}+bc $$
The starting inequality is equivalent to $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{t}{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}a}{8}.\dfrac{3\left(2a+b+c\right)^2+16}{2a+b+c}+bc}}\ge 3, t=\frac{3\sqrt{3}+1}{3}. $$Now, using $$\sqrt{u}\ge \frac{2u(u+3)(3u+1)}{(u+1)(u^2+14u+1)},$$which is true by squaring. Denote $$u=\frac{t}{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}a}{8}.\dfrac{3\left(2a+b+c\right)^2+16}{2a+b+c}+bc},$$which says that we need to prove $$f(u_1)+f(u_2)+f(u_3)\ge 3.$$I verified by Maple.

I hope to see simple idea. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-Let me to change the notation, please, which is for working with functions. So we have $x,y,a\ge0; \space xy+ay+ax=1;\space M=\sqrt{\dfrac{81\sqrt3-27}{26}}\approx2.08747285$.

Prove that $f(x,y,a)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{xy+3a}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ax+3y}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ay+3x}}\ge M$

Since $y=\dfrac{1-ax}{a+x}\iff x=\dfrac{1-ay}{a+y}$ we form the function

$$f_a(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x+a}{-ax^2+(3a+1)x+3a^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{x+a}{ax^2+(a^2-3a)x+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{x+a}{3x^2+(3a-a^2)x+a}}$$
The derivative of the first of the three addents equating to $0$ gives the equation
$$x^2+2ax-1=0\Rightarrow x_0=-a+\sqrt{a^2+1}$$ from which a local minimum among the allowed values of $a$. It follows the function in $a$
$$f_a(x_0)=f_a(-a+\sqrt{a^2+1})=g(a)$$ which itself take a local minimum. Approximative calculations give for the value $a\approx0.58$
$$g(0.58)\approx2.08747432\\\hspace0.8cm M\approx2.08747285$$
Almost equal values.....with still $g(0.58)\gt M$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Trän Nk Trang You are welcome. My only goal with this comment was to collaborate with you on your problem keeping in mind that it is maybe too hard for usual methods to solve these inequalities.

Comment: I thought it would be simple but I was wrong

Comment: Uvw helps well, I think

Comment: Trän Nk Trang. Tell me, please, dear friend, what does mean **Uvw** I know well French and Spanish but my English is quite deficient. is it an acronym?

Comment: Trän Nk Trang Thank you very much.  I am sick now and I'll see after your link with uvw method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof.

The desired inequality is written as
$$\sqrt{\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{ab + 3c}}
+ \sqrt{\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{bc + 3a}}
+ \sqrt{\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{ca + 3b}}
\ge 3. \tag{1}$$

Let
$$x := {\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{ab + 3c}}, \quad y :=
{\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{bc + 3a}}, \quad z := {\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{ca + 3b}}.$$

By AM-GM, we have
$$\sqrt x = \frac{x}{\sqrt x}
= \frac{x}{2\sqrt{\frac{x + 1}{4} \cdot \frac{x}{x + 1}}}
\ge \frac{x}{\frac{x + 1}{4} + \frac{x}{x + 1}} = \frac{4x(x + 1)}{x^2 + 6x + 1}.
$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{4x(x + 1)}{x^2 + 6x + 1} + \frac{4y(y + 1)}{y^2 + 6y + 1} + \frac{4z(z + 1)}{z^2 + 6z + 1} \ge 3. \tag{2}$$

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca = 1, r = abc$.

(2) is written as
\begin{align*}
  &-729\,{r}^{4}+ ( -3402\,p\sqrt {3}-4374\,{p}^{2}+30618\,\sqrt {3}
  +25110\,p-20412) {r}^{3}\\
  &\quad + ( -10206\,{p}^{3}\sqrt {3}-6561
  \,{p}^{4}+153252\,{p}^{2}\sqrt {3}+75330\,{p}^{3}\\
  &\quad\qquad\qquad -665820\,p\sqrt {3}-
  276264\,{p}^{2}+416178\,\sqrt {3}+185976\,p-297675) {r}^{2}\\
  &\quad +
  ( -121014\,{p}^{3}\sqrt {3}+31590\,{p}^{2}\sqrt {3}-432054\,{p}^
  {3}+3299040\,p\sqrt {3}+1863756\,{p}^{2}\\
  &\quad \qquad \qquad-5533272\,\sqrt {3}+1475808\,p
  -7165962 ) r\\
  &\quad +119718{p}^{2}\sqrt{3}+449946p\sqrt{3}+193644
  {p}^{2}-1250220\sqrt{3}+39846p-57215\\
  &\ge 0. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Since $q^2 \ge 3pr$ and $p^2 \ge 3q$, we let
$$p = \sqrt 3 + t, \quad r = \frac{1}{3p + s}, \quad s, t \ge 0.$$
(3) is written as $\frac{f(s, t)}{(3\sqrt{3}+3t+s)^4} \ge 0$
where $f(s, t)$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients.
Thus, (3) is true.

We are done.

Comment: $(3)$ is a simple idea indeed.

Comment: @BobDobbs We only need to do simple polynomial manipulations (expand, collect). However, it is not nice by hand.

Answer (score 0):

*My second proof using Holder inequality*:

The desired inequality is written as
$$\sqrt{\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{ab + 3c}}
+ \sqrt{\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{bc + 3a}}
+ \sqrt{\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{ca + 3b}}
\ge 3. \tag{1}$$

By Holder inequality, we have
$$\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{\frac13 + \sqrt 3}{ab + 3c}}\right)^2 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (ab + 3c)(a + b)^3
\ge \left(\frac13 + \sqrt 3\right)(2a + 2b + 2c)^3. \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that
$$\left(\frac13 + \sqrt 3\right)(2a + 2b + 2c)^3 \ge 9\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (ab + 3c)(a + b)^3. \tag{3}$$

We use the pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca = 1, r = abc$. Using $p^2 \ge 3q$, we have $p \ge \sqrt 3$.

(3) is written as
$$( 189{p}^{2} - 405p - 54) r + (24\sqrt{3} - 19)p^3 - 81{p}^{2} + 162 \ge 0. \tag{4}$$

Since $(24\sqrt{3} - 19)p^3 - 81{p}^{2} + 162 > 0$, we only need to prove the case that $189{p}^{2} - 405p - 54 < 0$.

Note that
$$0 \le (a - b)^2(b - c)^2(c - a)^2
= -27r^2 + (-4p^3 + 18p)r + p^2 - 4$$
which results in
$$r \le - \frac{2}{27}p^3 + \frac13 p + \frac{2}{27}(p^2-3)\sqrt{p^2 - 3}. \tag{5}$$

From (4) and (5), it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &( 189{p}^{2} - 405p - 54)\cdot 
 \left(- \frac{2}{27}p^3 + \frac13 p + \frac{2}{27}(p^2-3)\sqrt{p^2 - 3}\right)\\
 &\qquad + (24\sqrt{3} - 19)p^3 - 81{p}^{2} + 162 \ge 0.
\end{align*}
which is true for all $p \ge \sqrt 3$.

We are done.

Comment: Nice proof @RiverLi

Comment: @TATAbox Thanks.